# can't get “memberof” to work in my OpenLDAP config

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP on a Debian 7.7 server.

While basic auth seems to work, I can't get the "**memberof**" overlay to work.

Being new to LDAP, all that *memberof* config seems overly complex to me - despite having read numerous tutorials...

In my current config I *mostly* followed the tutorial at http://gos.si/blog/installing-openldap-on-debian-squeeze-with-olc

I say mostly, because I skipped the step in the "**Creating a LDAP Database**" section. The reason is, that I can't create my database since the desired olcRootDN (`cn=admin,dc=indunet,dc=it`) is already taken. It's already there right after installing `slapd` using `aptitude`. Maybe it's a left-over from a previous installation, but I did `aptitude purge slapd` and even removed the `/var/lib/ldap/` directory and made sure there were no more .ldif files around, so I have no clue why `cn=admin,dc=indunet,dc=it` comes from.

So, I tried to configure the pre-existing database `olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config` this way (I've added the highlighted entry):
[image]

For reference, the parent group (the "database") has these attributes:
[image]
(fullsize [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgzXN.jpg))

I can see this config only when logging in with the bind DN `cn=admin,cn=config`. I can't add users/groups there (probably because that's just for configuration, right?). So I added a few groups and a user using the DN `cn=admin,dc=indunet,dc=it` in phpLDAPadmin.

In Apache DS that config looks like this:

[image]

I'm not sure if `memberOf` should be visible in this screen (I guess so), but anyway that attribute is defenitely *not* being sent to the client that depends on it.

It wouldn't surprise me if my config is completely broken, but I spent 2 days trying to fix this and honestly have run out of ideas...

## Update

As time passed and I've played around with LDAP, this is my new current tree:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I guess, you dont quite understand how a memberof works.

http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/guide.html#Reverse%20Group%20Membership%20Maintenance

you should create cn=Udo as inetOrgPerson in 'cn=users,dc=indunet,dc=it', 
then you should create cn=plainuser as groupOfMembers or groupOfUniqueMembers in 'cn=groups,dc=indunet,dc=it', 
then you should add 'Member' or 'UniqueMember' attribute to cn=plainuser,cn=groups,dc=indunet,dc=it.

After that you will get 'MemberOf' attribute in 'cn=Udo,cn=users,dc=indunet,dc=it'.

also, remind, this attribute is hidden normally. to see this attribute, you must enable the displaying of operational attributes.

Comment: Yes, I'm a complete novice to LDAP and so may confuse some things. You say I should create cn=Udo in `cn=users,dc=indunet,dc=it`. I already have it in `ou=users,dc=indunet,dc=it` ("ou", not "cn"). What's the difference? Please note my update in the meantime. I have no `cn=groups,dc=indunet,dc=it` anymore. Is my tree completely wrong now? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: This answer is spot on. Getting by this information without being told is almost impossible.